# ADD CODE ON CLICK OF VOID BUTTON IN NETSUITE

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Once the user clicks on the standard void button in NS, I wanna do something first before it is committed. Since there is no function triggered from client event script, I tried to use User event before submit, but I cannot see a way to identify whether the event is fired by VOID or by SAVE button. Do you have any suggestions/ideas on what work around can be done?

Comment: What record type specifically are you trying to void?
In my NetSuite instance, when I press Void on a Cheque it takes me to a page to create a Journal Entry which would reverse that cheque.

Comment: Check the answer I just posted. Hopefully, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

## Usage & Explanation

- Deploy as a User Event script on the Journal record
- This code will find the related transaction that's being voided and *before it's voided* will change its memo to "This transaction has been voided!"
- Note that "*before it's voided*" refers to when you click the "Save" button on the **Voiding Journal** record, not specifically when you press the "Void" button on the original transaction.
- You can use this as a basis for performing other actions on the `voidedRecord` object.

### SuiteScript 1

```
function beforeSubmit(type) {
    if (type == 'create') {
        var voidRecord = nlapiGetNewRecord();
        var voidedRecordId = voidRecord.getFieldValue('createdfrom');
        var voidedRecordType = voidRecord.getFieldValue('transform');

        var voidedRecord = nlapiLoadRecord(voidedRecordType,voidedRecordId);
        voidedRecord.setFieldValue('memo','This transaction has been voided!');
        nlapiSubmitRecord(voidedRecord);
    }
}
```

### SuiteScript 2

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/record'],
    function (record) {
        function beforeSubmit(context) {
            if (context.type == context.UserEventType.CREATE) {
                var voidRecord = context.newRecord;
                var voidedRecordId = voidRecord.getValue({fieldId: 'createdfrom'});
                var voidedRecordType = voidRecord.getValue({fieldId: 'transform'});
                
                var voidedRecord = record.load({
                    type: voidedRecordType,
                    id: voidedRecordId
                });
                voidedRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'memo',
                    value: 'This transaction has been voided!'
                });
                voidedRecord.save();
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note this assumes that you have the option set to "Use Reversing Journals to Void Transactions".  If that option is not turned-on, then there is no J/E created.  The base transaction is set to posting=N, zeroed-out and saved.  A voided transaction cannot be resurrected.